# What can you do with a metaclass that you can't do with __new__?

Tags: python, python-3.x

It seems to me that a lot of the typical examples of metaclass use that people give in which the `__init__` method of the metaclass modifies the `cls` argument in some way could just be accomplished by modifying `__new__` on the class instead.

What are some practical things which can be accomplished by making a metaclass, but not by modifying `__new__`?

Comment: Anything that involves how a class object is initialized? When you write a class definition statement, `class Foo: pass` that is an implicit call to the `type` constructor, `type('Foo', (object,), {})`. Anything you want to control about that process has to happen in a metaclass (by overriding the default metaclass, `type`'s behavior)

Comment: Here's an example, suppose you want to modify the behavior of `print(MyClass)` where `MyClass` is some class. Then there's nothing you can really do about that in the definition of `MyClass`, you have to define a metaclass that overrides `__repr__` or `__str__`. Or consider `enum`. That relies heavily on metaclasses. A simple example, suppose you have an enum type, `Color`, you can iterate over the enums by iterating over the class `for color in Colors:`, again, you have to define `__iter__` on the metaclass

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I see. Thanks for the examples, that makes a lot of sense. A lot of the examples I've seen tend to be about the behavior of the objects of the class, which I think is why I was confused.

Comment: You can do pretty much everything using MetaClass like change the attributes, change inheritance of the class, change the property and method of the class

Comment: @wetler Right but what I was saying is, all of those can be accomplished by overriding `__new__` in the class. The example given above of modifying the `__str__` of _the class itself_ makes sense, but isn't something I've personally wanted to do.